# Setting up a website to document current and past Human Rights abuses

Tags: copyright

Can recent (2012-2016) historical emails and documents/reports pertaining to the  Human Rights abuses of a marginalized group of people be published?

Comment: Who's emails and documents will greatly impact the answer. For example if they are yours it would change the answer.

Comment: It is the proof of the systemic Human Rights abuse of a marginalised group of people.  The site does not set out to lay blame, rather, it is recording the strugglescurrently on the ground.

Comment: You've got the start of an excellent question here. How did you obtain the e-mails and documents? If they were sent to you for example versus finding them on the hard drive of a computer you purchased.

Comment: Some were sent directly to me by the conciliator who had been appointed to investigate issues .  Others had been sent to the conciliator who then ccd me into.

Comment: That depends greatly on jurisdiction and who you accuse of violating human rights. If you accuse the government of the state where you currently reside or of an allied state, it will very certainly bring you into trouble. See Chelsea Manning, Julian Assange or Edward Snowden.

Comment: Just because you are accusing the government of a state where you reside does not mean it will get you into serious trouble with the state.  Some people accuse the United States of human rights abuses as a matter of course.  Manning, Assange, and Snowden were involved in leaking classified information to the public, which is very different than making an accusation of torture, of a violation of due process, or of a violation of a provision of the Universal Declaration of Human Rights, for example.

Comment: As Jason said, it's very difficult. Some may be subject to publication bans if they've been through a court, but aside from that, I can't think of any criminal offences that could possibly arise, assuming that the information is factually correct. There's also libel, which is a civil tort that covers this, but I'm probably straying away from your question now.

Answer (score 1):

Ask one of the high-profile law school human rights clinics, a copyright law professor, or the legal staff of a major human rights NGO; or see who they suggest talking to.

This is not quite typical fair use commentary on an issue of public concern, but it is still addressing an issue of public concern and there is a strong argument that First Amendment protections should apply, especially if the release is done, for example, via news media.  An experienced expert or motivated researcher will know or can spend some time with the relevant case law.